# Is there a way to get rid of /Index in url of every controller in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am a bit new to the MVC so started off with MVC3 with ASPX engine.
my scenario is, that when I create a controller it automatically generates an Action named "Index" so suppose if I create a "Users" Controller + some actions, it would look something like this.

UserController

- Index
- Add
- Delete
- Edit
- other actions

Then I create another controllers named "Products", "Company", etc with lets say the same set of Actions,

So normally when I would go to the link ../Users/Index I have the logic to show all users and it would do the same for ..Product/Index and ..Company/Index etc. It would show all products and all companies respectively.

This part of story is working good.

Now what I want to achieve is, I want to get rid of /Index everywhere in the url, not just for these three controllers, but for every controller that I create in future.
I want to consume "Index" Action but in a way that it doesn't need being typing everywhere.
It just makes me remember of old days where there used to be /index.html.

I have seen the links like these,
[MVC Routing get rid of /Index in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568119/mvc-routing-get-rid-of-index-in-url)
they suggest i change the route for a specific situation, but I want this done not just in one or two controllers but every controller there is in my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every route, specify `Index` as the default action, e.g.:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: I don't know how but with just one such route you mentioned, it worked for all the controllers. I am no longer required to type /index in the url.
Thanks